# Exit Pipeline if user did not enter values for Active Choice Parameterized pipeline build

Tags: if-statement, jenkins, null, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I wish to abort the pipeline if the user did not select any value for Active Choice parameter for single/multi choice/string pipeline parameter.

For example I have Active Choices Reactive Parameter Named "IPAddress" of Type "Multi Select" with Groovy Script as below:

```
if (Location.equals("MyTown")) {
return["DDL1", "DDL2", "DDL3", "DDL4"]
} else if (Location.equals("Your Town")) {
return["DDP1", "DDP2"]
} else {
return ["Select an IP from the drop-down"]
}
```

Thus, once I run the pipeline i see "Select an IP from the drop-down" for IPAddress.

Now, If the user does not select anything from the dropdown the pipeline should fail & abort.

In the pipeline script I have written the below condition check which fails to check the condition despite user ignoring to select any IPAddress.

```
def ex(param){
    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
    error('BAD PARAM: ' + param)
}

pipeline {          

    agent any       

        stages {

            stage ("Pre-Check Parameters") {        

                steps {

                echo "Pre-Check called in pipeline"

                 script {
                    if ("${params.IPAddress}" == null) {ex("IPAddress")}
                    //if ("${params.myEnv}" == null) {ex("b")}
                    //if ("${params.myLoc}" == null) {ex("c")}
                    }            
               }              
             } 
          }
      }
```

Can you please suggest what could be the issue here ?

Comment: sorry ,your suggestion DOES NOT work. @user7294900.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any constraint against using the `input` step?

```
def days=''
pipeline{
agent any;
stages {
    stage('master'){
       steps{ 
           script { 
               try {
                    timeout(time:10, unit:'SECONDS') {
                        days = input message: 'Please enter the time window in number of days', ok: 'Fetch Statistics', parameters: [string(defaultValue: '90', description: 'Number of days', name: 'days', trim: true)] 
                    }
                }
                catch (err){
                   error("No custom value has been entered for number of days.")
                }
           }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine if your string is empty you can use the method `.trim()`. It will remove leading and trailing spaces from your string. The two magic words are "[Groovy Truth](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-semantics.html#_strings)". An empty string is false in Groovy. This makes it easier to evaluate conditional expressions. Means in your case, if you use `.trim()` in combination  with an if conditional then the Groovy Truth value of the string will be used for the evaluation.

Your pipeline should work if you change it to the following. It will check if your variable is null or empty:

```
script {
    if (!params.IPAddress?.trim()) {
        ex("IPAddress")
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion however, this worked for me: if ("${params.IPAddress}" == "") {ex("IPAddress")} i.e empty quotes instead of null.